# Dual fuel generator - using natural gas on propane input

Tags: electrical, generator

Instead of using a conversion kit to make a generator be able to take natural gas through the gasoline side of it (e.g. Nash Fuel or Century Fuel Products), is there a way to feed natural gas in through the propane intake in a way that would work - much how gas grills can take one or the other via  simple adapter which I think affects the air mixture or something like that?

EDIT:
The tri fuel ones that also produce a clean sine wave (low THD) are very expensive - I found GEN85KIDF which is an inverter type and produces a clean sine but it's only dual fuel so was looking into the best way to add natural gas support

Comment: For a gas grill, you change the gas orifice and the pressure regulator which amounts to the whole fuel metering system for the grill.  For an engine, the fuel metering is much more exact.  I have this question as well and would like to see some answers, but I think it might not be possible or would be an expensive conversion.

Answer (score 2):

There are conversion kits you can buy that go both directions (one requires a smaller nozzle for the gas injection than the other), but those kits are not cheap (the Nash Fuel you mentioned runs $160 or so).

What would probably be easier than converting your existing generator is to buy a tri-fuel generator instead. These accept natural gas, propane and gasoline without serious modification (some are as easy as turning a knob to select which fuel is being used).

Comment: Nice, I have seen a few Dual, but haven't seen a tri.  Guess I need to look around some more!

Comment: The tri fuel ones that also produce a clean sine wave (low THD) are very expensive - I found GEN85KIDF which is an inverter type and produces a clean sine but it's only dual fuel so was looking into the best way to add natural gas support

Comment: Are you saying you've seen a kit which can convert a propane input to a natural gas input on a generator?

Comment: @g491 The only one I've seen make that claim is the one you yourself mentioned: Nash Fuel. Not cheap, but [this Amazon listing says it works for some types](https://www.amazon.com/Nashfuel-Pressure-Propane-Generator-Conversion/dp/B00EP1QW7A) (i.e. it's not universal)